# Binding Array of Objects to kendo listview

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-template, kendo-listview

I have a case where my ViewModel has an Array such as,

```
{id: 0,
 Name: "KendoListView1",
 dataitems: [{id: 1, itemName: "Kendo"}, {id: 2, itemName: "List"}]
},

{id: 2,
 Name: "KendoListView2",
 dataitems: [{id: 3, itemName: "Kendo"}, {id: 4, itemName: "List"}]
}, 

{id: 3,
 Name: "KendoListView3",
 dataitems: []
}
```

So now when I bind my ViewModel to the ListView template, my template needs to handle the case where, if there is an Array I show the Array elements in the view, and when the Array is empty I just need to show the Name (KendoListView1, KendoListView2) and not the Array elements

I need a template structure like this:

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">  
# if(dataitems.length) { #
    <div>
         //Show all the items Names from the Array
    </div>
# } else {#
    <div>
         //Show all the Names
    </div>
# } #
</script>
```

I tried to iterate through the Array using a for loop and display the items when I have an Array, but in runtime, once I add a new item into the Array, the for loop would run through all the items again and display all items.

Can anyone help me in this case

Comment: `Array` is a global object in Javascript. If you type `Array.length` in Chromes dev tools, it will return 1.  Rename Array to a non-reserved identifier

Comment: Your first snippet, is that 3 distinct objects or one array containing 3 objects? Is each of those the datasource for a bespoke ListView instance or is one listview instance rendering all 3 of those items with a child listview in it rendering your `dataitems` array?

Comment: Else consider only the first item, with id 0. When we add this object to ViewModel, we need to find a template to support it

Comment: I would strongly advise against your approach. A ListView is not suited to be nested and you'd need to wrap scripts inside your template. You should pre filter and flatten your data-source and display a listview per Item.

Answer (score 0):

A `.Map().Join()` can be used for rendering your sometimes filled `dataitems`.

Template

```
  <script id="my_funky_listview_template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
    # if (dataitems.length) { #
      #:
        itemName + " items: " + dataitems.map(function(item){return item.itemName;}).join(",")
      #
    # } else { #
      #:
        Name
      #
    # } #
    </div>
  </script>
```

Declaration / configuration

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#listview").kendoListView({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    template: kendo.template($("#my_funky_listview_template").html())
  });     
});
</script>
```

If the data source delivers any content that is missing a `Name` or `dataitems` property the javascript console will log a `'<property>' is not defined.` message and the listview will not appear.